# Optimum parameters for 1280x727 screen?

Tags: fontsize, geometry, paper-size

I'm going to experiment with using my Android tablet to lecture from this coming semester: moving between LaTeX PDFs and a handwriting note app.  My usable screen size is 1280 x 727 pixels (there's a status bar which I can't remove without rooting, which I'm hesitant to do...)

What are the optimum parameters (geometry, font type and size etc) for a LaTeX file to look best on this device; or where should I start experimenting to find the best solution?

In the past I've simply used ConTeXT with S8 paper size and a helvetica 20 pt font, but I'm moving back to LaTeX (simply because most of my notes for this subject are already in LaTeX and I don't want to spend time converting them).  And as I've just discovered, S8 provides a 4:3 screen ratio, and I need something closer to 9:5.

Comment: you can use geometry package to set the paper size to exactly 1280x727 in some units or other the exact units don't matter so much so long as you choose a suitable relative font size, then you can zoom the pdf to full screen without clipping.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Make that an answer?

Answer (score 4):

you can use geometry package to set the paper size to exactly 1280x727 in some units or other the exact units don't matter so much so long as you choose a suitable relative font size, then you can zoom the pdf to full screen without clipping